# When to use to and from

Tags: prepositions

Which one is mostly recommended to speak

> 1) We played a game and I won **to** him

or

> 2) We played a game and I won **from** him

Answer (score 5):

Neither.

The choice of prepositions is dependent on the requirements of the particular words in the sentence, in this case the verb *win*.

The verb "win" (past tense *won") doesn't take an indirect object like this. You can say:

> We played a game, and I won.  *(implicitly he lost)*

or explicitly using the verb "beat", which gives a different meaning to its direct object:

> We played a game, and I beat him.

The object of the verb "won" is the prize, for example:

> We played a game, and I won a teddy-bear from him.

Comment: Note that this is not a question about _to_ and _from_, or a question about English grammar in general. Like many questions about prepositions, it is a question about the requirements of a **specific** word, in this case, the verb _win_.